# Remove src from all iframes and add it on click

Tags: javascript, iframe, src

I'm trying to remove the src values from all my iframes and then on click load the srcs to the ones matched by a selector.

Right now I have a block of code that empties the src of my iframes and creates a variable with the src info.

After that I'm trying to check if an iframe src is empty and if so, have a function that on click of a link will add the corresponding src values to the returned iframes.

The code is as follows, but the click part is not working.
Naturally I'm not sure about the IF part, as well, since the thing as a whole is not working.

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

var iframesa = $j('iframe');

iframesa.each(function() {
    var srca = $j(this).attr('src');
    $j(this).data('src', srca).attr('src', '');
});


$j(document).ready(function(){

   if($j('iframe').attr('src') == '') { 

        $j('.evento-more').click(function() {
            $j(this).next().children('iframe').attr('src', function() {
                    return $j(this).data('src');
            });
        });

    }

});
```

The HTLM structure is something like this

```
<div class="evento-feed">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="evento-more">More</a>
      <div class="evento-desc">
         <div class="slide-text">
            <p>
               <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xxxx"></iframe>
            </p>
         </div>
         <div class="slide-text">
            <p>
               <iframe src="https://www.soundcloud.com/embed/xxxx"></iframe>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="evento-feed">
   <div class="wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="evento-more">More</a>
      <div class="evento-desc">
         <div class="slide-text">
            <p>
               <iframe src="https://www.mixcloud.com/embed/xxxx"></iframe>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And so on. The whole .evento-feed block gets repeated a few more times, although the content may vary

Is there anyone that can help me?

Comment: You don’t have the first part wrapped in `(document).ready`, so most likely it does not find any iframe elements at all.

Comment: @Tiago   Do you have control over the sites within the iframes? If so, do they belong to the same domain? Where and what exactly is `.evento-more`? Maybe some HTML would help a little.

Comment: @zer00ne No I don't, the iframes are youtubes embeds, soundclouds etc. I will update with the html, ty for the interest

Comment: @CBroe Ty, but the iframes are cleared, but they don't come back. Unfortunately having the first part inside the document.ready also didn't change anything, apparently.

Comment: Create a [mcve], please.